# @SpringBootTest does not load content of application-test.yml

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, spring-test

In this project I have to work with the older Spring Boot Version `2.2.13.RELEASE`.

I have a simple application-test.yml

```yaml
myapp:
  foo: test
```

Also a very simple AppConfig.java

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp")
public class AppConfig {
  private String foo;

  public String getFoo() {
    return foo;
  }

  public void setFoo(final String foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
}
```

This is the test class:

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = {AppConfig.class}, properties = "spring.profiles.active:test,local")
class MyTest {
  private final AppConfig properties;

  @Autowired
  IPLocatorServiceTest(final AppConfig properties) {
    this.properties = properties;
  }

  @Test
  void test() {
    assertThat(properties.getFoo()).isEqualTo("test")
  }
}
```

The Test fails. The `AppConfig` is not null, but the values are not loaded from the file.

I don't want to load the whole Spring application context with all of it's database stuff and thinks.
I just want to load some of my beans and the configuration.

## Answer

Because the answer below is not very detailed I'd like to provide the complete solution:

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(FeatureProperties.PREFIX)
public class FeatureProperties {
  public static final String PREFIX = "myapp.feature";
  private String foo;

  public String getFoo() {
    return foo;
  }

  public void setFoo(final String foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
}

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(FeatureProperties.class)
public class FeatureConfiguration {
  private final FeatureProperties featureProperties;

  public UsageConfiguration(final FeatureProperties featureProperties) {
    this.featureProperties = featureProperties;
  }
}

@SpringBootTest(classes = {FeatureConfiguration.class}, properties = "spring.profiles.active=test,local")
class FeatureServiceTest {
  // test code in here
}
```

This works like a charm and does only load the beans in the context, that are really wanted...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update:

You are missing the annotation `org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties` in your test.

Comment: This makes no difference. I simple use it because of: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19788. Also `:` seems to work...

Comment: I've updated my answer with the solution, take a look.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to rename your `application-test.yml` to just `application.yml`. This file should be in test/resources.
Then you should be able to avoid defining the properties part in @SpringBootTest.
Just write `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: This is exactly what I don't want. `@SpringBootTest` without classes does load the whole application context. Database Connection and all these things. This makes the test slow.